# Why does Mockito verifyNoMoreInteractions has problem with Scala default values

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito

For a mocked class I have a method for which I would like to test whether there are no more interactions then needed, which looks similar to: 
`def someMethod(someMandatoryParam: Int, canBeDefaultIds: Option[Ids] = None): Future[Failures] = {...}`

when I am mocking to invoke this method without the default parameter and I verify it that way:
`verify(someClass).someMethod(someInt)`
and then check if there was no more interactions:
`verifyNoMoreInteractions(someClass)`

I am getting an error that here was some unexpected interactions.

But when in implementation I change this method to use None instead of default value and verify:
`verify(someClass).someMethod(someInt, None)
 verifyNoMoreInteractions(someClass)`

It works correctly.

Is there a problem with Mocikto and default values in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default arguments is Scala specific feature which Java Mockito is likely not aware of. Consider how Scala code looks after `-Xprint:jvm` phase

```
abstract trait SomeClass extends Object {
  def someInt(a: Option): Option = a;
  <synthetic> def someInt$default$1(): Option = scala.None;
}
```

Notice how the default argument became just another method `someInt$default$1`. Try using [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) which is designed with Scala in mind, for example the following test passes

```
import org.mockito.{ArgumentMatchersSugar, IdiomaticMockito}
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

trait SomeClass {
  def someInt(a: Option[Int] = None) = a
}

class MockitoScalaDefaultArgsSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers with IdiomaticMockito with ArgumentMatchersSugar {
  "mockito-scala" should "handle default arguments" in {
    val someClass = mock[SomeClass]
    someClass.someInt()
    someClass.someInt() was called
    someClass wasNever calledAgain
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if there is any equivalent for verifyNoMoreInteractions or this is "Java" mindset specific?

Comment: @imaru `aMock wasNever calledAgain`. See https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala#idiomatic-mockito